# calling script_execute with a variable

Tags: gml, game-maker

I'm using GameMaker:Studio Pro and trying to execute a script stored in a variable as below:

```
script = close_dialog;
script_execute(script);
```

It doesn't work.  It's obviously looking for a script named "script".  Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: It is looking for a script named "close_dialog" and then executing that script.. Above code is exactly the same as `close_dialog()`

Comment: Works fine for me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mheu7mx3d62l4qp/Script%20Test.gmz?dl=0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question's quite old now, but in case anyone else ends up here via google (as I did), here's something I found that worked quite well and avoids the need for any extra data structures as reference:

```
scriptToCall = asset_get_index(scr_scriptName);
script_execute(scriptToCall);
```

The first line here creates the variable scriptToCall and then assigns to it Game Maker's internal ID number for the script you want to call. This allows script_execute to correctly find the script from the ID, which doesn't work if you try to pass it a string containing the script name.

I'm using this to define which scripts should be called in a particular situation from an included txt file, hence the need to convert a string into an addressable script ID!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have some confusion over how Game Maker works, so I will try to address this before I get around to the actual question.

GML is a rather simple-minded beast, it only knows two data types: strings and numbers. Everything else (objects, sprites, scripts, data structures, instances and so on) is represented with a number in your GML code.

For example, you might have an object called "Player" which has all kinds of fancy events, but to the code Player is just a constant number which you can (e.g.) print out with `show_message(string(Player));`

Now, the function `script_execute(script)` takes as argument the ID of the script that should be executed. That ID is just a normal number. `script_execute` will find the script with that ID in some internal table and then run the script.

In other words, instead of calling `script_execute(close_dialog)` you could just as well call `script_execute(14)` if you happened to know that the ID of `close_dialog` is 14 (although that is bad practice, since it make the code difficult to understand and brittle against ID changes).

Now it should be obvious that assigning the numeric value of `close_dialog` to a variable first and then calling `script_execute` on that variable is perfectly OK. In the end, `script_execute` only cares about the number that is passed, not about the name of the variable that this number comes from.

If you are thinking ahead a bit, you might wonder whether you need `script_execute` at all then, or if you could instead just do this:

```
script = close_dialog;
script();
```

In my opinion, it would be perfectly fine to allow this in the language, but it does not work - the function call operator actually *does* care about the name of the thing you try to call.

Now with that background out of the way, on to your actual question. If `close_dialog` is actually a script, your suggested code will work fine. If it is an extension function (or a built-in function -- I don't own Studio so what do I know) then it does not actually have an ID, and you can't call it with `script_execute`. In fact, you can't even assign `close_dialog` to a variable then because it does not have any value in GML -- all you can do with it then is call it. To work around this though, you could create a script (say, `close_dialog_script` which only calls `close_dialog`, which you can then use just as above.

Edit: Since it does not seem to work anyway, check whether you have a different resource by the name of `close_dialog` (perhaps a button sprite). This kind of conflict could mean that `close_dialog` gives you the ID of the sprite, not of the script, while *calling* the script directly would still work.

Comment: I appreciate your well thought out post, but the only thing that worked, other than using the id directly, was the answer I just posted.

Comment: Maybe it is me who is confused then? I'll have to figure out why this does not work. :P

Comment: I tried it out (in GM 8.1) and got exactly what I expected. If I have a script close_dialog in my game the exact code you wrote in your question calls that script. `show_message(string(close_dialog))` shows 2 in my case, the script's ID. If this really does not work for you, it must be because of a bizarre change between GM 8.1 and GM Studio. Edit: And in that case, wouldn't you be better off writing a function that *calls* a script by name, instead of return its ID?

Comment: It definitely does not work in GMS.  But your idea of writing a function that calls a script by name probably does make a bit more sense  :)  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much discussion on the forums, I ended up going with this method.

I wrote a script called script_id()

```
var sid;
sid = 6; //6 = scriptnotfound script :)

switch (argument0) {
    case "load_room":
        sid = 0;
        break;
    case "show_dialog":
        sid = 1;
        break;
    case "close_dialog":
        sid = 3;
        break;
    case "scrExample":
        sid = 4;
        break;
}

return sid;
```

So now I can call script_execute(script_id("close_dialog"));

I hate it, but it's better than keeping a spreadsheet... in my opinion.

Comment: AT LEAST use the script names instead of the numbers.. On top of that is there a reason you need to use a string? - if you wish to actually parse user input this method is hard to extend, much better to create a ds_map() at gamestart which has as key the string and as value the numbers. The value can then be gained through (and the script executed): `script_excecute(ds_map_find_value(SCRIPTMAP, "close dialog"))`

Answer (score -2):

There's also another way, with execute_string();
Should look like this:

```
execute_string(string(scriptName) + "();");
```

Comment: execute_string does not exist in GameMaker: Studio. It was removed after GameMaker 8.1.